# Why do I get mixed http/1.1 and h2 requests to the same server?

Tags: apache-2.4, http2

I have set up my apache2 to support http2 roughly following https://http2.pro/doc/Apache. Everything runs smoothly, but when I check connections to my Nextcloud and Roundcube instances in Chromiums dev tools, SOME requests are executed via h2, but most are still http/1.1, during the same page load.
Is this normal?

Of course, the websites are called via https (Let's Encrypt) and have an A+ rating in the Qualys SSL test.

Comment: yes, not all systems are using h2. thats a normal situation. meaning you onlx enabled an additionally protocol instead of a use only

Comment: What do you mean "not all systems"? I am not only talking about the same computer, but even the same page reload. The Chromium Dev Tools Networktab shows a long list of requests, some of which are h2 and some are http/1.1.

Comment: you could only try to disallow http1.1 but at all chrome decides whats the best technique for the request

Comment: Removing http/1.1 from the Protocols line does not seem to have any effect.There are some questions around discussing how to disable http/1.0, and that does not seem to be that easy. It is a little bit hard to compare if this is right (Chromium decision because it is the actually better way) or an issue, as you hardly find sites nowadays that on request from one server ...